# Magento 2.1.7(With Sample Data) Installation error at 65%

Tags: magento2, installation, magento-2.1.7, timeout

After the installation process, 65 % completed, the Magento 2.1.7 not processing. How can i solve the error.

Note: Using Xampp

Comment: Just restart your xampp server and re install Magento.

Comment: Please  enable logs and add logs to question  and also you can review
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3241